# Data frame problem with NaN and Null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing issue in dataframe with null and NaN values.

So I want only replace NaN with 0 and null values will remain same.
But when I am using numpy or dataframe fillna method it replaces all Nan as well as Null values by 0 
My dataframe looks like this

```
Age DOB
69  1990-10-01
49  1989-04-04
NaN null
54  null
NaN null
```

And I want it to convert like this

```
Age DOB
69  1990-10-01
49  1989-04-04
0   null
54  null
0   null
```

Comment: Please try to be more descriptive while asking questions. Like what is your DataFrame look like and what steps you have tried till now to solve the problem

Comment: I have used df.replace(np.NaN, 0, inplace=True) but not working
df.fillna(0) its also not working

Answer (score 1):

Try:
    `df = df.replace({pd.np.nan: None})`

Comment: It's also replacing null values by 0

Comment: I am looking for only replace NaN by 0, Not null values

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
df=df.replace(to_replace = np.nan, value =0)
```

Comment: It's also replacing null values by 0

Comment: I am looking for only replace NaN by 0, Not null values

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your support, I found the solution

```
df = df.replace({pd.np.nan: None})
```

Which solved my problem

Comment: it's also helpful to apply a function to just a series